# Insert/Update multiple records in EntityFramework Core 2.0

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have to insert around 100 time-stamped measured values for each measuring point into a table every day in one go. The model is

```
public class MeasuredValue
{        
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public int MeasuringPointID { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

where the primary key is the combination of Timestamp and MeasuringPointID. Most of the time the values will be *new*, meaning that I could insert them without key conflict, which would allow me simply this:

```
List<MeasuredValue> measuredValues = ... read from somewhere ...

var ctx = new DatabaseContext(config.ConnectionString);

foreach (var mv in measuredValues)
    ctx.MeasuredValues.Add(mv);

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Under certain conditions, however, data need to be (partly) re-read which would let the above code throw a duplicate key exception, maybe because there is only one duplicate key (timestamp).

What would be an efficient solution for this problem?

Should I call `SaveChanges` in a loop for every measured value, catch the exception and do an update then? Should I always try to find the key and update the record if it exists, otherwise insert? Something else?

**Update**

note that *100 records* sounds very few. Consider, however, that the number of measuring points may be 1000 which would make 100000 records altogether every day!

(Also I added the pre-core EntityFramework tag because I think this problem would be the same there)

Comment: Can you explain a little more on how/why the data will re-read? Can these be isolated or flagged somehow to be handled differently?

Comment: Yes. There may be several reasons for re-reading. F.e. the software allows to transform the measured values read by a device by a factor and an offset. If these settings were chosen wrong by the technician who initially configured the software, it may be necessary to correct these settings and re-read sometimes several months of data :-( Of course this could be corrected by an SQL command but the technicians mostly don't know how SQL. What they do know is how to set back the timestamp from which to read data.

Comment: The case I described would probably allow to delete the entire time range before trying to insert the corrected data. If this is really faster than searching and inserting/updating, it would be worth a try.

Comment: Would it be possible to filter out the duplicates in measuredValues in memory before processing?

Comment: For that I would have to do quite a big SELECT before or the equivalent in EF. Maybe I should write a few performance tests for the various strategies. I just thought there would be a general approach to this. But it looks like it depends ... as always ;-)

Comment: How about bulk insert into a staging table, then logic to insert/update to main table?

Comment: Thanks for your time! So the staging table would be identical to my actual target table? And the bulk insert would be a single call to SaveChanges, right? Could you elaborate on the insert/update logic? I don't understand what is the benefit of it compared to looking for already existing keys directly in the target table and then doing insert/update as required.